How can I find GDI leaks that occur during dynamic loading/unloading of a DLL?
If I load and unload a DLL written in Delphi, that uses dxForms.pas(DevExpress) (only use, no form is created) then the GDI-handles shown by Task Manager increases by every load/unload. I read the GDI-handle table and compare the list of brushes, pens, etc before loading the DLL and after unloading it. There is no difference. But the sum of all handles is not equal to the count of GDI-Handles shown by Task Manager. If I repeat the load/unload often enough then the max GDI-handle count is reached (10000) and the process is terminated.
How can the difference between the number of GDI handles displayed in Task Manager and the total number of handles in the list of the GDI handle table be explained? Of course, I have read the explanation at https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html. But it is not clear to me how such objects are created that are not stored in the GDI handle table.
The number of unreleased handles varies from DLL to DLL, but on average is about 15 handles.

Please provide a code example of how you are loading/unloading your DLL files. Also minimal code for a DLL example will be handy so se we can test your scenario by ourselves. Without the additional information we can only guess.

Have you tried SysInternals Process Explorer to see what exactly is being created and leaked?

Yes, I have checked this with SysInternals Process Explorer, NirSoft GDIView, and by my self with GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS) before LoadLibrary and after FreeLibrary. All handle count are identical. I have now found out that the problem seems to be due to unreleased cursor resources.

I have found the problem: the cursors allocated in cxControls are not released if unload the dll.
I have reported this to DevExpress.
